# I am not geting data in contact object but i am geting in Lead while integrating with mailchimp

Tags: integration, mail-chimp

I am trying to integrate my developer org with mailchimp. i mapped the fields of Lead and Contacts. When i am creating contact on mailchimp i am getting it as Lead in salesforce but i am not getting in contact. I am not getting any error. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

That's how Mailchimp's integration works. You should carefully review their [integration guide](https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-mailchimp-for-salesforce/#Turn_on_data_sync_and_lead_creation).

> After you've chosen your sync settings, turn on data sync to make sure that Mailchimp and Salesforce communicate and share data regularly. **You also have the option to allow Mailchimp to create new leads in Salesforce.**

Emphasis mine. When a new record is created from Mailchimp to Salesforce, that record is a Lead.